# I need help solving this hyperbolic equation

Tags: equation-solving, differential-geometry

I have some data and I'd like to calculate the radius of curvature.  The formula is:
$$R_{oc}\space Sinh\left[\frac{D_{LSS}}{R_{OC}}\right]=\frac{s_*}{\theta_*}$$
Noting that $s_*$ is **sh**, $\theta_*$ is **angle**,$D_{LSS}$ is **distance**, $R_{OC}$ is **Roc**, I tried using **Solve** to solve the equation:

```
Solve[Roc*Sinh[distance/Roc] == sh/angle, Roc]
```

and got:

`Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.`

So I tried supplying some values and doing it numerically:

```
sh = 7.74*^21; 
angle = 1.0411/100.; 
distance = 5.32*^23;
NSolve[Roc*Sinh[distance/Roc] == sh/angle, Roc]
```

And I got the equation spit back out at me.  Can someone help me solve this equation either analytically or numerically?

**Note:** I suspect a third option might be to use optimization, but I just can't figure out how to set up the function.

Comment: That doesn't look like an equation with a closed form solution. You'd need `FindRoot[]` with a good starting point for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sh = 774*^19;
angle = 10411*^-6;
distance = 532*^21;

arg = NArgMin[
   {(Roc*Sinh[distance/Roc] - sh/angle)^2, Roc > 10^20},
   Roc, WorkingPrecision -> 30] // N

(* 3.63412*10^23 *)

FindRoot[
 Roc*Sinh[distance/Roc] == sh/angle,
 {Roc, 10^23}]

(* {Roc -> 3.63412*10^23} *)

NSolve[
  {Roc*Sinh[distance/Roc] == sh/angle,
   10^22 < Roc < 10^24}, Roc][[1]]

(* {Roc -> 3.63412*10^23} *)
```